# Gap between inline-block div element and inline-block hr tags

Tags: html, css

How do you remove the gap between inline-block div and inline-block hr elements as shown below? I have tried setting margin to 0 and removing any white space, but the gap still remains.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 10%;
  height: 79px;
}

hr {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: thick solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<hr/>
```

Comment: vertical-align:top

Comment: I have added vertical-align: top to the hr element, but there is still a gap between the div and hr. Is there any way to completely remove the gap? Thank you.

Comment: vertical-align:top to both element not only the hr

Comment: Thank you it is now working.

Comment: Actually, I have one more question. Why does this property work despite that the width of the hr tag is set to 100%? If the hr element is in the next line, will it assume the "top" of the div element as the bottom of the div?

Comment: read the duplicate to understand why